# Most efficient way to loop finding items not in a list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to improve the efficiency of a script that takes lists and counts how many items aren't in another 'master' list (`list_of_all_items`).

It feels like there might be a more efficient way of doing this, perhaps through combining the querying somehow?

```
purple_count, brown_count, blue_count = 0, 0, 0

for item in list_of_purple_items:
    if item not in list_of_all_items:
        purple_count += 1

for item in list_of_brown_items:
    if item not in list_of_all_items:
        brown_list += 1

for item in list_of_blue_items:
    if item not in list_of_all_items:
        blue_count += 1
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your help. I ran a quick test to see what the best way was using a big test case:

```
    my original: 30.21s
           sets: 00.02s
         filter: 30.01s
  sum generator: 31.08s
```

Amazing how much more efficient it is using sets.

Thanks again all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use *sets* so you don't have to keep looping:

```
set_of_all_items = set(list_of_all_items)
purple_count = len(set(list_of_purple_items).difference(list_of_all_items))
brown_count = len(set(list_of_brown_items).difference(list_of_all_items))
blue_count = len(set(list_of_blue_items).difference(list_of_all_items))
```

This is far more efficient, because set intersections only require a loop over one of the two sets involved; each item can then be tested against the other set in constant time. The looping is done in C code (when creating the `set` objects and when calculating the difference).

Using a set for all items is not really required as `set.difference()` takes any iterable, but it is slightly faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import random
>>> all = range(10000)
>>> random.shuffle(all)
>>> all[:-1000] = []
>>> some = [random.randrange(10000) for _ in range(1000)]
>>> timeit.timeit('len(set(some).difference(all))', 'from __main__ import some, all', number=10000)
0.9517788887023926
>>> timeit.timeit('len(set(some).difference(all))', 'from __main__ import some, all; all = set(all)', number=10000)
0.90407395362854
```

Comment: Didn't realize that `set`s work down at the C level, even more reason to use them now!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` with a generator expression, and convert your list to `set` that is more efficient for checking the membership :

```
main_set=set(list_of_all_items)
sum(1 for i in set(list_of_purple_items) if i not in main_set)
```